# Trying to print permutations/possible words given a length and a binary tree of characters

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

Given a length and a binary tree of characters, say:

```
  a
 / \
b   c
```

I'm trying to print out all combinations of words. Example of word size 2, the combinations of words would be: aa, ab, ac, ba, bb, bc, ca, cb, cc. I was able to figure out how to print the tree if it was only the left side, but run into complications when I include the right. For example a tree of say:

```
    a
   /
  b
 /
c
```

I can get the expected output. Here's the code I have so far, I just need to somehow print the right side also. I tried many combinations of things, but can't seem to get anywhere. Any ideas?
Here's what I have so far... Oh, by the way, root2 and root3 are just copies of root initially.

```
void printWords(Node* root, Node* root2, Node* root3, string word, int n)
{
    
    if (n == 0 || root == NULL)
    {
        cout << " " << (word) << endl;
        return;
    }

    while (root2 != NULL)
    {
        string tempWord;
        tempWord = word + root2->data;
        

        root2 = root2->left;
        printWords(root->left, root3, root3, tempWord, n - 1);
    
    }
```

Comment: I would just take all the letters out of the tree, and put them into an array. The tree isn't useful unless you have to follow the links, e.g. the only words for the first example are "ab" and "bc".

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I understand the tree isn't useful and it'd be easier just to put the characters in an array and go from there, I was just seeing if it was even a possibility to just get the desired results by just traversing through the tree but I can't seem to find a way.

Comment: The array can be iterated, which allows recursion to be used to form words. A tree is typically traversed using recursion. So if you traverse the tree with recursion, and form the words with recursion, you end up with a big recursive mess. So yes, you can do it.

Comment: BTW, it is not permutation but cartesian product you want. You just need a way to iterate over all letters of the tree, then it is mostly `for (char letter1 : tree) for (char letter2 : tree) {/*..*/}` (than you can extend to further dimension with a `std::vector<tree::iterator>`).